# Custom Team Foundation Server Plugins: ISubscriber interface for public use?

Tags: plugins, tfs

With Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2010 came a new Plugin concept that allows you to hook on TFS events and execute custom code. To do this you have to implement the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ISubscriber interface and place your compiled assembly at a specific location on the TFS.

What I wanted to ask is whether this extension point is thought to be used by developers other than Microsoft. Or is this extension point only for internal use by the Microsoft team itself and subject to change.

The reason why I came up with this question is because this extension point is actually only "documented" on blogs. None of this is officially documented on MSDN. So for me it looks more like a hack.

Comment: A famous plugin is the TFS Aggregator which uses exactly that. Have a look here: https://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

We use it. The assembly goes into a folder labelled "plugins" which implies to me it's supported functionality.